# When you've been doing something wrong because that's the way you've always done it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example word-senses:

- when you've been pronouncing a word a certain way just because you've never heard another person pronounce it
- when you've been doing a physical exercise wrong because you've never been corrected / you never noticed

Sample sentences:

- I'm pronouncing it that way because X
- It's a case of X
- Today I overcame X with my kicking technique thanks to my new martial arts instructor

Words I tried which don't seem to work:

- status quo
- https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/that-s-it-s-always-the-way : none of the listed words seem to indicate incorrectness, and using "incorrect" or "wrong" as a prefix/qualifier does not seem natural

Criteria for the "best" word: perhaps the one that gives closest indication to the phenomenon (best captures the intended word-sense)

Is a compound word or phrase acceptable: yes

Comment: I defy anyone to replace *X* in each of those 3 sample sentences with the same word or phrase and make 3 grammatical sentences.  Please clarify your requirements for the form and function for our suggestions to replace *X*.

Comment: "I'm pronouncing it that way because I've only ever seen it in writing." (You've never _heard_ another person pronounce it!)

Comment: Hi @HighPerformanceMark. Feel free to be fluid in form, as long as the word you suggest is more succinct in capturing the phenomenon than using a sentence. I hope this is clear from the "criteria" that I've included (as prompted by stackexchange when I was writing the question). If not then let me know how else I can clarify the question. There are already some candidate answers that are coming close.

Comment: I notice that your title includes not only doing something because that's the way you've always done it, but doing it **incorrectly**. That really makes it difficult to find a simple phrase. Is that really necessary if "incorrectly" could be added as a qualification?

Comment: @David no. If incorrect could be added as a natural qualifier, it's fine. I also mentioned trying to find words with which I could add a single word qualifier to indicate that, but I failed in my search.

Comment: It's fair enough to ask, but I don't think you'll find anything in common use for this one. English has a wealth of expressions, but these tend to relate to a particular aspect of things and the context in which they are used provides the additional shades of meaning. And for those who are not a native speakers, that is the hard part.

Answer (score 4):

***Ingrained*** is often used to describe behavior, beliefs, attitudes, etc. that are wrong and, ideally, corrected. Of course good or correct things can be ingrained as well, but the "difficult to change" aspect makes the adjective well-suited for something longstanding that is deemed to be wrong.

**ingrained** (adj.)

> (Of a habit, belief, or attitude) firmly fixed or established;
> difficult to change.
>
> *Widows and widowers aren't baggage-free either, and even those stalwarts who have remained single for half a lifetime will be
> carrying armfuls of **ingrained** habits and cherished routines.*
>
> *I have not yet stopped buying the paper, as I simply find it too hard to break such an **ingrained** habit, but each morning I spend a
> little longer in the newsagent's before picking it up.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ingrained)

---

> In the worst case, faults of spelling are more easily corrected than
> an **ingrained** bad pronunciation. [*Proceedings of the High School
> Conference of November ... 1910*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Proceedings_of_the_High_School_Conferenc/vhFDAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22faults%20of%20spelling%20are%20more%22) p.113

> If you sense that a good apple is beginning to go bad, it's important
> to act quickly and intervene before the bad habits or behavior
> becomes **ingrained**. [Sember and B. Sember; *Bad Apples: How to
> Manage Difficult Employees...*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Bad_Apples/sR7rDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22If%20you%20sense%20that%20a%20good%20apple%20is%20beginning%20to%20go%20bad%22&pg=PT71&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> In my experience, as students become aware and "practised" in noting
> and correcting their personal mistakes, many previously **ingrained**
> errors are continually highlighted and, eventually, corrected as
> students write. [*Forum*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Forum/I_yTYVvbxu0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=In%20my%20experience,%20as%20students%20become%20aware%20and%20%22practised%22%20in%20noting) p.44 (1982)

> Overeating is typically a combustible combination of disturbing
> feelings and wrong thoughts, coupled with deeply **ingrained**
> behavior patterns and easily available food. [Stephen Arteburn; *Lose
> It for Life Workbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lose_It_for_Life_Workbook/rNI6HeiYH1AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=ingrained%20behavior%20that%20is%20wrong&pg=PA117&printsec=frontcover) (2004)

Answer (score 4):

To express this idea in the most common, comprehensible manner, I recommend:

> I’m doing this **from force of habit**.

As it says in the [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/force-of-habit):

> “If you do something from or by force of habit, *you do it because you
> have always done it in the past*…”

The section I have italicized relates almost perfectly to the title of this question, although it does not include the idea of *incorrectness*, which would hardly fit the first example. But you can easily qualify this to say:

> He does it *incorrectly* **from force of habit**

(I would suggest that one should only try to make an abstract noun to describe the idea if you’re  a professional psychologist talking to your peers — and then it would probably be in German† and off-topic.)

†*Gewöhlichkeitsabhängigtendenz* comes to mind (mine, not a native German speaker’s).

Answer (score 3):

> I'm pronouncing it that way because I was **blissfully unaware** the correct version was ….
> It's a case of being **blissfully unaware**.
> Today I overcame my **blissful ignorance** regarding my poor kicking technique thanks to my new martial arts instructor.

Quoting https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/unaware :

> blissfully unaware (=not knowing about something unpleasant): *Sam was blissfully unaware that they were laughing at him.*

A few example usages from https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blissfully-unaware :

> Has the actress been in la-la land, blissfully unaware of current events?
> Times, Sunday Times (2009).
>
> The singer seemed blissfully unaware as he performed with the two female singers in his band.
> The Sun (2009).
>
> The mouse seems blissfully unaware that it is about to plucked from the snow and will shortly be lunch for a great grey owl.
> Times, Sunday Times (2014).
>
> My daughter was snoozing away in her car seat, blissfully unaware.
> Times, Sunday Times (2014).
>
> Those newlyweds were still blissfully unaware  and butterflies turn into ritual and routine.
> Christianity Today (2000).

Answer (score 2):

The term **mumpsimus** is used for persistent misuse, including that due to ingrainedness:

> *mumpsimus* [noun]
>
> adherence to or persistence in an erroneous use of language,
> memorization, practice, belief, etc., out of habit or obstinacy ...

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mumpsimus)]

Most dictionaries, however, require the stubbornness qualification.

Comment: The story behind _mumpsimus_ displays considerable stubbornness. It's a mispronunciation of L _sumpsimus_ which had slipped into some priest's recitation. When corrected, he responded that he preferred his pronunciation to the official one.

Comment: Sounds like the way English usually develops.

Comment: "Is used" by whom?

Comment: Albert P' Rayan [[Edex Live](https://www.edexlive.com/opinion/2020/oct/31/are-you-a-mumpsimus-15507.html)] +1 for a start. The dictionaries do the research normally considered necessary on ELU.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good ones here but I've got another:

**automatic pilot** or **autopilot**

Originally this was a term used in engineering.  Here's a definition from the field of psychology:

“The term ‘automatic pilot’ describes a state of mind in which one acts without conscious intention or awareness of present-moment sensory perception.”  [Source](https://www.mindfulnessmuse.com/mindfulness/pros-and-cons-of-being-on-automatic-pilot)

Examples:

I went home after my appointment by accident.  The car was on autopilot.

My first semester of music school was mainly about technique.  I had to turn off my autopilot, practice really slowly, and learn how to use arm weight for shifts, and arm circles for string crossing.

Answer (score 2):

It's a case of [*not knowing better.*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+know+better)

"Better" implies that there's better way to do things.

- I'm pronouncing it that way because *I don't know any better.*
- I'm pronouncing it that way because *of not knowing better.*
- It's a case of *not knowing better*.
- Today I overcame *not knowing better* with my kicking technique thanks to my new martial arts instructor.

Truly, *ignorance* can fit in any of these, but this is a little less harsh.